# github action failing? tar empty archive, docker run failed with exit code 1

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions

This is the project structure:

```
- parent/
|- .github/workflows/
|- frontend/
|- ...
```

This is the .yml file within workflows:

```
name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: "12.x"

    - name: Install dependencies
      working-directory: frontend
      run: npm install

    - name: Build
      working-directory: frontend
      run: npm run build

    - name: Deploy Files
      uses: appleboy/scp-action@master
      env:
        HOST: ${{  secrets.aws_pull_host }}
        USERNAME: ${{ secrets.aws_pull_username }}
        KEY: ${{ secrets.aws_pull_private_key }}
      with:
        working-directory: frontend
        source: build/
        target: "/home/build/site/testDir/"
        strip_components: 1
```

Whenever the action gets to the step `Deploy Files`, i get the error:

```
tar: empty archive
tar all files into /tmp/891353322/bC24rHhFAi.tar
exit status 1
##[error]Docker run failed with exit code 1
```

First time working with github actions so I am pretty lost with this error. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5):

Kept messing with it, finally figured it out:

```
- name: Deploy Files
      uses: appleboy/scp-action@master
      env:
        HOST: ${{  secrets.aws_pull_host }}
        USERNAME: ${{ secrets.aws_pull_username }}
        KEY: ${{ secrets.aws_pull_private_key }}
      with:
        source: frontend/build/
        target: "/home/build/site/testDir/"
        strip_components: 1
```

Comment: This saved me a lot of time, tnx!